# How do I fix this AgoraRTCException error?

Tags: video, stream, webrtc, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am new in agora and I want to create a video app.
It was working all the time however now it starts giving me this error.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error 
AgoraRTCException: AgoraRTCError INVALID_OPERATION: Can't publish stream, haven't. joined yet
```

Unfortunately, they have not highlighted where the error is located?

Answer (score 0):

You should call AgoraRTCClient.join() success before call [AgoraRTCClient.publish()](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html#publish)

Answer (score 0):

For .join() to work, the channel name and agora token must be created together, and then those two matching variables must be used in the call to .join().  It's easy for them to get out of sync unless you create them together and make sure they stay together.